# Bilinear function bounded by norms of arguments

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $v_1 \in X$ and $v_2 \in Y$, $v = (v_1, v_2) \in X\times Y$, $X$ and $Y$ being normed linear spaces. Let $\phi$ be a continuous bilinear function.

Why

$$\|\phi(v_1, v_2)\| \leq K\cdot\|v_1\|\cdot\|v_2\|\quad ?$$

If the function is continuous, I can understand something of the type

$$\|\phi(v_1, v_2)\|\cdot\frac1{\|v\|} \leq K$$

But I'm having trouble getting from one expression to the other.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What can we say about the map $x\mapsto\,\big(y\mapsto \phi(x,y)\big)$?

Comment: I'm thinking something on the line of: "y \mapsto \phi(x,y)" is continuous. So we have a constant $K_1$ for $\frac{||\phi(x,y)||}{||y||}$. And then, using the same argument for $x\mapsto\,\big(y\mapsto \phi(x,y)\big)$, I can get an $K = K_1 * K_2$ such that my statement in this thread is true. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Your constant $K_1$ may depend on $x$. Note that we have a map $X\to Y^*$.

Comment: I didn't follow your last phrase. $K_1$ shouldn't depend on $x$, right?

Comment: Yes, shouldn't depend. But as you defined it, it does depend. But, just forget about $K_1$.

Comment: can you provide further help? I haven't had the time to think properly about this nor I have a bibliographical reference, but I would like to know why the result follows. I've tought about the mapping you said as a hint but I also couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What I thought is that the given map $\Phi:X\to Y^*$ is continuous, let its norm be $K$. Then $\|\Phi(x)\| \le K\cdot \|x\|$. But note that $\Phi(x)\in Y^*$ so it means $\|\Phi(x)(y)\|\le \|\Phi(x)\|\cdot\|y\|$. $\ \ $(Actually, $\|\Phi(x)\|$ is what you called $K_1$.)

Comment: Wow. I think that does it. I was having some trouble thinking about $\Phi:X\to Y^*$ since it's a map to another map. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

Since $f$ is continuous bilinear, we have that $f$ is continuous at 0.

Then, for an open ball $B_\mathbb{R}(0, \epsilon)$, we have that $f^{-1}(B_\mathbb{R}(0, \varepsilon))$ is open in $X$ x $Y$. (continuity implies that the pre-image of an open set is open).

Then, we deduce the existence of $\delta > 0 $ such that:

$||x||<\delta \Rightarrow ||f(x)||<\varepsilon$

Then, since X x Y is a linear space, we have that $x = (z, y) \in X$ x $Y$; then, $\delta z \in X$ and $\delta y \in Y$. Then $\delta (z,y)$ = $\delta x$ belongs to the cartesian product of $X$ x $Y$

$||\delta*x|| < \delta \Rightarrow ||f(\delta*x)|| \varepsilon$

We then have that

$\delta ||x|| < \delta \Rightarrow ||\delta^2f(x)|| \varepsilon$

This follows from bilinearity (take delta out of each argument of the function, each at a time, by fixing the other argument).

Thus, if $||x||<1$, we have that $||f(x)|| < \frac{\varepsilon}{\delta^2}$

Then, $||f||^* = sup\{||f(x)||: ||x||<1\} < \infty$

Now consider $f(x, y)$ = $||x||*||y||*f(x^*,y^*)$ where $x^*$ = $\frac{x}{||x||}$ (this is a standard operation)

Ok, now we have the conclusion, since

$||x||||y||f(x^*,y^*) \leq ||x||*||y||*||f||^*$

You can name $||f||^*$ as "K" and get the desired result.

Kudos to my math TA.